# How to gather and output all data in an Array as well as tracking current data

Tags: c++

The first issue I have is I need to figure out a way for every time the do while loop occurs it tracks the amount of lockers that are assigned by the user as well as amount of books that user has inputed. If the user is to choose choice 3 the program is to output a full list of all the assigned information for every locker number in order, in the same output format as choice 2. Also at the end of the code how can I add up all of the assigned lockers amount of money so I know when it is over 150 and willie is to steal the money? Thank you in advance I hope this was clear enough.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

//Creates type locker
struct locker
{
  short lockerNumber;
  string studentLastName;
  short numOfTextbooks;
  float amountOfMoney;

};

int main()
{
  const int MAX_LOCKERS = 101;  //All lockers in array
  const int STEALABLE_MONEY_LIMIT = 150.0;  //Stealable money for willie.

  //Variable Declarations
  short menuChoice;
  short lockerNumberChoice;
  short lockerNumberDuplicate;
  short numOfTextbooksChoice;
  float amountOfMoneyChoice;
  string lastNameChoice;
  bool menuExit = false;

  //Array declaration   
  locker lockerArray[MAX_LOCKERS];

  //Preassigns all lockers to being unassigned.
  for(int i = 0; i <= MAX_LOCKERS - 1; i++)
  {
    lockerArray[i].studentLastName = "Unassigned";
  }

  //Magical code that helps with currency
  cout.setf(ios::fixed);
  cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
  cout.precision(2);

  do
  {
    //Menu for user
    cout << "\t Locker Menu \t" << endl;
    cout << "\t ----------- \t" << endl;
    cout << "1.) Add a locker \t" << endl;
    cout << "2.) Print contents of locker \t" << endl;
    cout << "3.) Output all locker contents \t" << endl;
    cout << "4.) Delete a locker \t" << endl;
    cout << "5.) Exit \t" << endl;

    //Output amount of occupied lockers
    cout << "There are n occupied lockers" << endl;
    //Output avg number of textbooks
    cout << "Average number of textbooks: " << endl;  

    //Input menu choice
    cout << "Enter a menu choice: ";
    cin >> menuChoice;

    switch (menuChoice)
    {


      case 1:

        //Assigns locker number with the same number in the array.
        cout << "Locker Number: " << endl;
        cin >> lockerNumberChoice;

        //Duplicates their input
        lockerNumberDuplicate = lockerNumberChoice;

        //Helps array organize their input
        lockerNumberChoice = lockerNumberChoice - 101;
        lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].lockerNumber = lockerNumberDuplicate;

        //Assigns last name with same locker in array as above choice.
        cout << "Student Last Name: " << endl;
        cin >> lastNameChoice;
        lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].studentLastName = lastNameChoice;

        //Assigns amount of text books with same locker from first choice.
        cout << "Amount of text books: " << endl;
        cin >> numOfTextbooksChoice;
        lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].numOfTextbooks = numOfTextbooksChoice;

        //Assigns amount of money to same locker in first choice.
        cout << "Amount of money: " << endl;
        cin >> amountOfMoneyChoice;
        lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].amountOfMoney = amountOfMoneyChoice;

        break;

      case 2:
        //Asks user to select a locker.
        cout << "Select a locker to display information about: " << endl;
        cin >> lockerNumberChoice;
        //Helps array find their number
        lockerNumberChoice -= 101;

        //Filters out unassigned lockers.
        if(lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].studentLastName == "Unassigned")
        {
          cout << "This locker is  unassigned" << endl;
        }

        else
        {
          //Outputs information on locker
          cout << "Locker Number: " << lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].lockerNumber << endl;
          cout << "Last Name: " << lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].studentLastName << endl;
          cout << "Amount of Textbooks: " << lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].numOfTextbooks << endl;
          cout << "Amount of Money: $" << lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].amountOfMoney << endl;    
        }

        break;

      case 3:
        cout << "\t Lockers \t" << endl;
        cout << "\t ------- \t" << endl;

        break;

      case 4:
        //User inputs locker to be emptied
        cout << "Enter a locker number to be emptied: " << endl;
        cin >> lockerNumberChoice;

        //Helps arrayt select user input
        lockerNumberChoice -= 101;

        //Filters out user input
        if(lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].studentLastName == "Unassigned")
        {
          cout << "This locker is already empty" << endl;
        }

        //Empties out array data on that locker and makes it unassigned.
        lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].studentLastName = "Unassigned";
        lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].numOfTextbooks = 0;
        lockerArray[lockerNumberChoice].amountOfMoney = 0.0;

        break;

      case 5:
        //exits switch statement and code
        cout << "Thank you for chosing this program! " << endl;
        menuExit = true;

        break;


    }
    //If this happens willie steals all the money
    if(lockerArray[MAX_LOCKERS].amountOfMoney > STEALABLE_MONEY_LIMIT)
    {
      cout << "Willie robs the lockers. " << endl;
      lockerArray[MAX_LOCKERS].amountOfMoney = 0.0;
    }

  } while (menuExit != true);









  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `lockerArray` has`MAX_LOCKERS` elements in it. Valid indices are `0` thru `MAX_LOCKERS - 1`. Your `for` loop conditional should read `i < MAX_LOCKERS`, otherwise you'll try to access `lockerArray[MAX_LOCKERS]` which is out of range.

Comment: Use a combination of `std::cout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));` and `std::put_money(value)` to output monetary values, instead of your current precision settings. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money

Comment: Why are you subtracting 101 from the `lockerNumberChoice`?

Comment: I do that because in the problem the choices of lockers are between 101 and 201 so to make it fit into the array i subtract.